# How to count values that greater than a value in an array

Tags: mongodb

Data structure is like bellow:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5031e3f0a606e8ef48c7da6b"), 
"hitTime" : [ 1345446896, 1345446943, 1345446991 ], 
"tag" : "a" 
}
```

I want to get entries that have `hitTime`>1345446991 so that I can rank the tag popularity.

How do I do this? Or is there other data structures that are convenient to do this incremental count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation:

> That is, when "value" is inspected, if it is an array, each value in the array is checked.

Using the [MongoDB documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ValueinanArray), your query should look something like this:

```
db.collectionName.find({
    hitTime : {
        $gt : 1345446991
    }
});
```

I am not sure if this works properly, but you might get the idea. =)